# Selecting the most recent entry on a timestamp cell

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have these two tables:

```
User:
=======================
  id  |  Name | Email 
=======================
  1   | User-A| a@mail
  2   | User-B| b@mail
=======================

Entry:
=================================================
  id  |  agree |       createdOn        | userId
=================================================
  1   | true   | 2020-11-10 19:22:23    |   1
  2   | false  | 2020-11-10 22:22:23    |   1
  3   | true   | 2020-11-11 12:22:23    |   1
  4   | true   | 2020-11-04 22:22:23    |   2
  5   | false  | 2020-11-12 02:22:23    |   2
================================================
```

I need to get the following result:

```
=============================================================
  Name    |   Email    |   agree     |       createdOn           
=============================================================
 User-A   |  a@mail    |   true      |  2020-11-11 22:22:23
 User-B   |  b@mail    |   false     |  2020-11-12 02:22:23
=============================================================
```

The Postgres query I'm running is:

```
select distinct on (e."createdOn", u.id)
u.id , e.id ,u."Name" , u.email, e.agree, e."createdOn" from "user" u
inner join public.entry e on u."id" = e."userId"
order by "createdOn" desc
```

But the problem is that it returns all the entries after doing the join! where I only want the most recent entry by the `createdOn` cell.

Comment: `distinct on (u.id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the latest entry per user. For this, you need the user id in the `distinct on` clause, and no other column. This guarantees one row in the resultset per user.

Then, you need to put that column first in the `order by` clause, followed by `createdOn desc`. This breaks the ties and decides which row will be retained in each group:

```
select distinct on (u.id) u.id , e.id ,u."Name" , u.email, e.agree, e."createdOn" 
from "user" u
inner join public.entry e on u."id" = e."userId"
order by u.id, "createdOn" desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use row_number to select the latest rows then do the join

```
SELECT * FROM USER A 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY CREATEDON DESC) AS RN
      FROM ENTRY
  ) K WHERE RN = 1
) B
ON A.ID = B.USERID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Having createdon = max(createdon) function.  Group By User